# bamboo file path passed as string

Tags: bamboo

I am setting up a pipeline on bambool. It's to manage a prometheus repo. I was previously using drone.

On drone a docker container would spawn and essentially run

```
docker run --volume $PWD:/data --workdir /data --rm --entrypoint=promtool prom/prometheus:v2.15.2 check rules files/thanos-rules/*.rules
```

On bamboo, according to the logs, it seems to be running

```
docker run --volume $PWD:/data --workdir /data --rm --entrypoint=promtool prom/prometheus:v2.15.2 'check' 'rules' 'files/thanos-rules/*.rules'
```

where each argument is a string. This breaks the regex. How can I have the argument passed as a file path instead of a string? Here are some screenshots of what I have tried
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting the entrypoint to `/bin/sh` and then the command to `-c "promtool check rules files/thanos-rules/*.rules"`  works